# jpa-Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I had created entity in google app engie datastore using JPA.  I set the id as follows

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long s;
```

After i deployed my applicaiton it give identity (i.e) unique value.but igive 1001,1002,1003 ....as id.But i wnat 1,2,3,4,5 like that.how to achive this?

Comment: I think to have to do something like this : [Answer][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2102110/1460591

Answer (score 0):

SEQUENCE is supported but don't think you have control over the range ... maybe it supports the sequence start point ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long s;
```